# How do I interpret n raise to decimal power?

Tags: math

I want to understand the physical significance of n raise to some decimal power.

Like when i say 2^5. I understand that it means 2 multiplied 5 times. But how do i analyse 2^0.1.

Please suggest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs to mathematics: http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2^0.1` is the tenth root of 2. For rational powers, `x^(p/q)=(x^p)^(1/q)` is a combination of powers and roots.

For general real numbers,

```
x^y = exp(log(x)*y).
```